# The $i^{th}$ term in the upper central series of the dihedral group of order $2^n$ is equal to the $(n-1-i)^{th}$ term in its lower central series.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, nilpotent-groups

**The Problem**: Prove that $Z_i(D_{2^n})=D_{2^n}^{n-1-i}$, where $D_{2^n}$ is the dihedral group of order $2^n$.

$Z_i(G)$ is the $i^{th}$ term in the *upper central series* of $G$, which is inductively defined by:$Z_0(G)=1$, $Z_1(G)=Z(G)$, and $Z_{i+1}(G)$ is the subgroup of $G$ containing $Z_i(G)$ such that $Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_i(G)=Z(G/Z_i(G))$.

$G^i$ is the $i^{th}$ term in the *lower central series* of $G$, which is inductively defined by: $G^0=G$, $G^1=[G, G]$, $G^{i+1}=[G, G^i]$, where $[H, K]=\langle[h, k]|h\in H, k\in K\rangle$.

**Source**: *Abstract Algebra, $3^{rd}$ edition* by Dummit and Foote.

**My Attempt**: Induction on $i$. Let $G=D_{2^n}$.

Base case: $i=0$. Trivial by the fact that $D_{2^n}$ is nilpotent of class $n-1$ and the theorem that if $G$ is nilpotent of class $c$, then $G^{c-i}\leq Z_i(G)$ for all $i\in\{0, 1, \dots, c\}$.

Induction Hypothesis: Suppose $Z_i(G)=G^{n-1-i}$. We need to show that $G^{n-2-i}=Z_{i+1}(G)$.

Now, we know that $G^{n-2-i}\leq Z_{i+1}(G)$-i.e., $G^{n-2-i}\subseteq Z_{i+1}(G)$-by the theorem used in the base case. Thus it suffices to show that $Z_{i+1}(G)\subseteq G^{n-2-i}$.

Note $Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_i(G)=Z(G/Z_i(G))$, where the RHS is abelian; thus $[Z_{i+1}(G), Z_{i+1}(G)]\leq Z_i(G)$ by a theorem about commutator groups. Hence $[Z_{i+1}(G), Z_{i+1}(G)]\leq G^{n-1-i}$ by the induction hypothesis, i.e., $[Z_{i+1}(G), Z_{i+1}(G)]\leq [G, G^{n-2-i}]$ (by the definition of $G^{n-1-i}$). **Screeching halt**.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Verify that the center of the dihedral group of order $2^{n+1}$ equals the $(n-1)$st term of the lower central series, and that $D_{2^{n+1}}/Z(D_{2^{n+1}})\cong D_{2^n}$. Then use induction on $n$.

Comment: Your notation and numbering for lower central series is nonstandard. It is far more common to use subindices (or some other notation, but not exponents) and to define $G_1=G$, $G_{n+1}=[G_n,G]$. E.g., McKay's *Finite $p$-groups*, Section 1.3; Hall's *Theory of Groups* Section 10.2; Gorenstein's *Finite Groups*, Section 2.3. Isaacs's *Finite Group Theory* uses exponents, but also defines $G$ to be the first term, not the zeroth term (Section 4A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are following Dummit and Foote's numbering for the lower central series, I will note that this is very much **not** standard. The use of exponents rather than other notation is uncommon as well, since it clashes with the common notation $G^k$ for the subgroup generated by the $k$th powers of elements of $G$.

From my bookshelf:

1. Susan McKay's *Finite $p$-groups* and Leedham-Green/McKay's *Structure of Groups of Prime Power Order* use $\gamma_i(G)$ to denote the $i$th term of the lower central series, and define $\gamma_1(G)=G$, $\gamma_{n+1}(G) = [\gamma_n(G),\gamma(g)]$.
2. Marshal Hall's *Group Theory* uses $\Gamma_n(G)$, and numbers them as above.
3. Isaac's *Finite Group Theory* uses exponents, but defines $G^1 = G$ and $G^{n+1}=[G^n,G]$.
4. Rotman's *Introduction to the Theory of Groups*, 4th Edition, uses $\gamma_i(G)$, and defines $\gamma_1(G)=G$.
5. Derek Robinson's *A Course in the Theory of Groups*, 2nd Edition, uses the same notation and numbering as Rotman, McKay, and Leedham.
6. Hanna Neumann's *Varieties of Groups* defines $G_{(1)}=G$ and $G_{(n+1)}=[G_{(n)},G]$.

I will follow the usual notation; we just prove that the upper and lower central series of $D_{2^{n+1}}$ coincide.

---

It is easier, I think, to work with induction on $n$ and prove it all in a stroke. Recall that we have already shown that:

> 1. [$D_{2^{n+1}}/Z(D_{2^{n+1}}) \cong D_{2^n}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4598246/742)
> 2. [$Z_{k}(G/Z(G)) = Z_{k+1}(G)/Z(G)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4594053/742)

We add the following:

**Lemma.** If $f\colon G\to K$ is a surjective group homomorphism, then $f(G_n) = K_n$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th term of the lower central series of $F$.

*Proof.* The result holds for $n=1$, since $f$ is surjective. Assume that $f(G_n) = K_n$. If $x\in G_n$ and $g\in G$, then $f(x)\in K_n$, $f(g)\in K$, so $f([x,g]) = [f(x),f(g)]\in [K_n,K]=K_{n+1}$, hence $f(G_{n+1})\subseteq K_{n+1}$. Conversely, if $y\in K_n$ and $z\in K$, then there exists $a\in G_n$ and $g\in G$ such that $f(a)=y$ and $f(g)=z$. Then $[y,z] = f([a,g])\in f(G_{n+1})$; since all generators of $K_{n+1}$ lies in $f(G_{n+1})$, we conclude that $K_{n+1}\subseteq G_{n+1}$, giving equality. $\Box$

We do induction on $n$. We denote $D_{2^k}$ by
$$D_{2^k} = \langle r,s\mid r^{2^{k-1}}=s^2=1, sr=r^{-1}s\rangle.$$

For $n=3$, we are working with the dihedral group of order $8$. The upper central series is $Z_0(D_8) = \{e\}$, $Z_1(D_8) = \langle r^2\rangle$, $Z_2(D_8) = D_8$. The lower central series is $(D_8)_1 = D_8=Z_2(D_8)$, $(D_8)_2=\langle r^2=[r,s]\rangle=Z_1(D_8)$, $(D_8)_3 = \{e\}=Z_0(D_8)$; so the two series coincide.

Assume the result holds for $D_{2^n}$, and let $G=D_{2^{n+1}}$. Then by looking at $D_{2^{n+1}}/Z(D_{2^{n+1}})\cong D_{2^n}$, we know that $G_1=Z_{n}(G)$, $G_2=Z_{n-1}(G)$, and so on, by lifting the upper and lower central series from the quotient. Then we just need to note that $G_{n-1}=Z_2(G)$ is cyclic, not central, and has order $4$, so $G_{n}$ must be equal to its unique subgroup of order $2$, namely $Z_1(G)$ (cannot be trivial, cannot be itself). This proves the two series for $D_{2^{n+1}}$ also coincide.

Comment: Great answer as always. I believe I still need to show that $(G/Z(G))_i=G_i/(Z(G))$ (using your notation for lower central series) for the proof to be complete; but thank you so much!

Comment: @DickGrayson: That's the lemma. The image of the $i$th term of the lower central series of $G$ in $G/Z(G)$ is the $i$th term of the  lower central series of $G/Z(G)$.

Comment: What was I thinking... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Exercise 6.1.15: Prove that $Z_{i}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)=D_{2^{n}}^{n-1-i}$.

Lemma 1:
Let $K=G/Z\left(G\right)$. There is the isomorphism $Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\cong Z_{n}\left(K\right)$.

Proof of Lemma 1:
Induct on the index $n$. It is obvious that $Z\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\cong 1$ so assume the induction hypothesis and consider the equality $Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z_{n}\left(G\right)=Z\left(G/Z_{n}\left(G\right)\right)$. For the left side,
\begin{align*}
    Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z_{n}\left(G\right)
    &\cong\left[Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\right]/\left[Z_{n}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\right]\\
    &=\left[Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\right]/Z_{n-1}\left(K\right)
\end{align*}
and, for the right side,
\begin{align*}
    Z\left(G/Z_{n}\left(G\right)\right)
    &\cong Z\left(\left[G/Z\left(G\right)\right]/\left[Z_{n}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\right]\right)\\
    &=Z\left(K/Z_{n-1}\left(K\right)\right)\\
    &=Z_{n}\left(K\right)/Z_{n-1}\left(K\right)
\end{align*}
which implies $Z_{n+1}\left(G\right)/Z\left(G\right)\cong Z_{n}\left(K\right)$. Thus the lemma.

Lemma 2:
$D_{2^{n}}$ is nilpotent of class $n-1$.

Proof of Lemma 2:
Observe that $D_{2^{2}}$ is abelian of class $1$. Then $D_{2^{3}}/Z\left(D_{2^{3}}\right)\cong D_{2^{2}}$ is nilpotent of class $1$ and Lemma 1 implies that $D_{2^{3}}$ is nilpotent of class $2$. The lemma is an easy generalization.

Proof:
Observe that $Z_{1}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)=Z\left(D_{2\cdot 2^{n-1}}\right)=\left\{1,r^{2^{n-2}}\right\}$ and
\begin{align*}
    Z_{2}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)/Z_{1}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)
    &=Z\left(D_{2^{n}}/Z_{1}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)\right)
    \cong Z\left(D_{2^{n-1}}\right)
    =Z\left(D_{2\cdot 2^{n-2}}\right)
    =\left\{1,r^{2^{n-3}}\right\}
\end{align*}
so the complete preimage of $Z_{2}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)/Z_{1}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)$ is
\begin{align*}
    Z_{2}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)
    &=\left\{Z_{1}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)\cup r^{2^{n-3}}Z_{1}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)\right\}
    =\left\{1,r^{2^{n-3}},r^{2\cdot 2^{n-3}},r^{3\cdot 2^{n-3}}\right\}
\end{align*}
and it is obvious that, in general, for $i<n-1$,
\begin{align*}
    Z_{i}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)
    &=\left\{Z_{i-1}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)\cup r^{2^{n-1-i}}Z_{i-1}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)\right\}\\
    &=\left\{1,r^{2^{n-1-i}},r^{2\cdot 2^{n-1-i}},\ldots ,r^{\left(2^{i}-1\right)\cdot 2^{n-1-i}}\right\}
\end{align*}
For completeness sake, in case $i=n-1$,
\begin{align*}
    Z_{n-1}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)/Z_{n-2}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)
    &=Z\left(D_{2^{n}}/Z_{n-2}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)\right)
    \cong Z\left(D_{2^{2}}\right)
    =\left\{1,r,s,sr\right\}
\end{align*}
and observe that $Z_{n-2}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)=\left\{1,r^{2},r^{2\cdot 2},\ldots ,r^{\left(2^{n-2}-1\right)\cdot 2}\right\}$ so the complete preimage of $Z_{n-1}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)/Z_{n-2}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)$ is
\begin{align*}
    Z_{n-1}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)
    &=\left\{Z_{n-2}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)\cup rZ_{n-2}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)\cup sZ_{n-2}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)\cup srZ_{n-2}\left(D_{2^{n}}\right)\right\}
    =D_{2^{n}}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, the commutation relation $sr^{2^{n-1}-k}s=r^{k}$ is equivalent to the commutator $sr^{2^{n-1}-k}sr^{k}=r^{2k}$ so the commutator subgroup is
\begin{align*}
    D_{2^{n}}^{1}
    &=\left\{1,r^{2},r^{2\cdot 2},r^{3\cdot 2},\ldots ,r^{\left(2^{n-2}-1\right)\cdot 2}\right\}
\end{align*}
Likewise, the commutation relation $sr^{2^{n-1}-2k}s=r^{2k}$ is equivalent to the commutator $sr^{2^{n-1}-2k}sr^{2k}=r^{4k}$ so
\begin{align*}
    D_{2^{n}}^{2}
    &=\left[D_{2^{n}},D_{2^{n}}^{1}\right]\\
    &=\left\{1,r^{4},r^{2\cdot 4},r^{3\cdot 4},\ldots ,r^{\left(2^{n-3}-1\right)\cdot 4}\right\}\\
    &=\left\{1,r^{2^{2}},r^{2\cdot 2^{2}},r^{3\cdot 2^{2}},\ldots ,r^{\left(2^{n-3}-1\right)\cdot 2^{2}}\right\}
\end{align*}
and, in general,
\begin{align*}
    D_{2^{n}}^{n-1-i}
    &=\left[D_{2^{n}},D_{2^{n}}^{n-1-i-1}\right]\\
    &=\left\{1,r^{2^{n-1-i}},r^{2\cdot 2^{n-1-i}},r^{3\cdot 2^{n-1-i}},\ldots ,r^{\left(2^{i}-1\right)\cdot 2^{n-1-i}}\right\}
\end{align*}
Thus the result.